# Error restoring backup in sql server. Old server version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When trying to restore a backup file (`.bak`) to SQL Server installed on my machine, I get the following error (steps that I follow to restore are: Right Click Database ---> Tasks ---> Restore)

Error message:

> *The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2500.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.2573. Either restore the database on a server that
>   supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this
>   server.*

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine and under Help --> About, I see the following:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    3.85.1132
```

Question: I already have Service pack 2, what should I down and from where to be able to restore my back up.

Comment: I know but whats higher than the service pack 2? A specific link you could suggest, please.

Comment: Are you trying to restore a system db or a user db?

Answer (score 1):

While you may have SQL Server 2008 R2 on your machine (or at least the management studio), that doesn't stop you having or connecting to a SQL 2008 Server - which it seems you are.

```
 select @@version
```

will tell you the server version and its number.

10.50.2500 is SQL 2008 R2 SP1

10.0.2573 is SQL 2008 SP1

NB - SQL 2008 SP2 (Service Pack 2) is different to SQL 2008 R2.

To restore this backup, you need to connect to a 2008 R2 or 2012 server.